# Java perform final action upon program termination?

Tags: java

I'm prototyping a concurrent/distributed system in Java.  When a process is terminated (e.g. ctrl+c on command line or red button in Eclipse) I would like to broadcast a message to the other processes (one final method) before it goes away.  Tried doing it with finalize() but to no avail.  Just pure java with threads, sockets, and a main loop.  Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914666/how-to-capture-system-exit-event

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried using [`Runtime.addShutdownHook`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29)?

Note the part in the documentation indicating that sometimes the JVM may abort without running shutdown hooks - this should be used as part of *graceful* shutdown, but shouldn't be assumed to *always* run. (Imagine if your network is suddenly cut off, for example - you *can't* broadcast a goodbye message in that case.)

Answer (score 2):

[`Runtime.addShutdownHook()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Runtime.addShutdownHook()`.

Answer (score 0):

[Runtime.addShutdownHook()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) is what you want.  This is only runs if the JVM is shutdowns normally