# Java - working with files atomically

Tags: java, concurrency, io

I am writing a Java application which should (among other things) generate a sequence of integers, starting with a given number (such as 900, 901, 902, 903, ... - the 900 is given as a parameter).

1. The current sequence value should persist when the application gets shut down and then started again.
2. When multiple instances of the application are running at the same time, they should share the same sequence (e.g. the union of the sequences generated by all instances should be the same as the sequence generated by a single instance, when running alone).
3. The administrator should be able to shut down the application and reset the current sequence value manually.
4. If the application crashes, the file should always stay accessible for other instances so that they can continue to work.

It was decided that the application would use a plain text file which would contain just the current number. When the application starts, it checks out if the file already exists and if not, creates it and writes the initial number into it. Everytime the application is about to generate a new number, it should read the current value inside the file, use it as the current sequence value, and then increment the number in the file.

I would like to now, how to do these two things atomically (with regards to other running instances of the same application):

- check out if a file exists and if not, create it and write a number into it
- read the current content of a file and then change it

Suggestions on how to achieve the listed goals in other ways are appreciated as well.

Comment: I'm really unsure which answer to mark as accepted - one of them truly answers the original question, the other one provides a solution which I'm going to try to convince other team members to use. It seems to me that the first one should probably get accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a lock file when a client writes the file and delete that lock file immediatly when the write process is done.

When the lock file is present other clients will not read or write the db file and wait until the lock file is deleted - simultanious reads are allowed.

You questions:

1. [Shutdownhook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914666/how-to-capture-system-exit-event)
2. Is solved by using the lock file mechanisem
3. Every client could create an ID file beside the db file and when that file is deleted by the admin the client shuts down.
4. Depends: if the shutdownhook is respected this should not be a problem but if the client is killed immediatly you dont have any chance to clean up.

Problems:

- If to many clients try to write the db file you cannot make shure that the first client will be served first.
- What happens if a clients crashes during the write process and is not able to clean up the lock file?
- What happens if two clients try to create the lock file at the same time? I think this depends on the os filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

Using a database sequence would be a simple and solid solution but you've decided it will be a file. Then you'll need to manage the distributed synchronization yourself. There are systems offering that, like Terracotta or Hazelcast. I would definitely use one of them instead of implementing a new one based on locking a file. Why not a database?

Comment: I agree, a DB or another Server would be a better approach but I think the prase _it was decided_ makes clear, that its not his choice and he have to use a plain text based db.

Comment: Why not a database - That's what I thought myself as well. My colleague wants a file based approach like this though. It would seem like an overkill however to install a full-fledged RDBMS just for the purpose of storing the current sequence value, it should rather be something like SQLLite. But AFAIK, with such database systems there is no easy way for the administrator to manually reset the current value, is there? Thank you for helping me.

Comment: You could use a trivial DB-Administration. (HSQLDB) [http://hsqldb.org/] is a db written in Java, uses simple files to store data and offers an admin access to the db.